# Where is my synchronous function? Trying to call "await" but I get the error "await is only valid in async function."

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary, asynchronous, puppeteer

Trying to write a script that uses puppeteer to login on a website, and emulate a list of devices as they go through each url. But, I am getting an error when I try to run the script: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. I am not very familiar with asynchronous functions so I tried to make every function asyncrhonous, I can't find my sychronous function. If it is when I map through each url, how do I make this synchronous?

```
//import devices from './puppeteerDevices'
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { devices } = puppeteer;



testedMobileDevices = ["Galaxy Note 3","Galaxy Note 3 landscape","Galaxy Note II","Galaxy Note II landscape","Galaxy S III","Galaxy S III landscape","Galaxy S5","Galaxy S5 landscape","iPad","iPad landscape","iPad Mini","iPad Mini landscape","iPad Pro","iPad Pro landscape","iPhone 4","iPhone 4 landscape","iPhone 5","iPhone 5 landscape","iPhone 6","iPhone 6 landscape","iPhone 6 Plus","iPhone 6 Plus landscape","iPhone 7","iPhone 7 landscape","iPhone 7 Plus","iPhone 7 Plus landscape","iPhone 8","iPhone 8 landscape","iPhone 8 Plus","iPhone 8 Plus landscape","iPhone SE","iPhone SE landscape","iPhone X","iPhone X landscape","iPhone XR","iPhone XR landscape","iPhone 11","iPhone 11 landscape","iPhone 11 Pro","iPhone 11 Pro landscape","iPhone 11 Pro Max","iPhone 11 Pro Max landscape","Nexus 10","Nexus 10 landscape","Nexus 4","Nexus 4 landscape","Nexus 5","Nexus 5 landscape","Nexus 5X","Nexus 5X landscape","Nexus 6","Nexus 6 landscape","Nexus 6P","Nexus 6P landscape","Nexus 7","Nexus 7 landscape","Pixel 2","Pixel 2 landscape","Pixel 2 XL","Pixel 2 XL landscape"];

const login = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const username = 'andrewbregman'
    const password = 'randompassword120948acndkla'  
    const base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

  await page.goto({base_url}/login);
  await page.type ('[name=username]', username);
  await page.type('[name=password]', password);
  await page.click('[type=submit]');
  await page.waitFor(5000);
  
}

const test = async () => {
    testedMobileDevices.map(device => {
    login();
    const base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
    const urls = ['myprojects', 'home', 'notifications']
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.emulate(device)

    urls.forEach(goUrls); 
    const goUrls = async (url) =>{
        await page.goto({base_url}/url)
        page.screenshot({
            path: "./screenshot.jpg",
            type: "jpeg",
            fullPage: true})
        await page.waitFor(100);
    }
    })
}

test();
```

Comment: The error message should have a line number.

Comment: `.map(device => {` that's at least one, but often you can't just slap `async` in front and be done.

Comment: `page.goto({base_url}/url)` isn't valid. You probably mean ```page.goto(`${base_url}/${url}`)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you should be sequencing these one at a time, otherwise you could have a ton of headless chrome browsers all competing for local resources in parallel.  So, all told, you need these changes:

1. Sequence the operations one after another to avoid too many resources in parallel.
2. Properly communicate back to the caller completion or errors.
3. Declared your string templates correctly.
4. Use `await` with all the promise-returning operations.
5. Remove all use of `.forEach()` since it is not promise-aware and `.map()` since you don't really want to be running all 100 or so of these in parallel.  Replace it with a regular `for` loop which inherits the parent's `async` declaration and is promise-aware and is easy to sequence with.
6. When you call this, log completion and catch and log any error.
7. As coded, this will abort upon first error.  You could modify the code to catch any error, log it, cleanup from that error and continue the loop with the next iteration.  You would need `try/catch` in a few places and the proper code in the `catch` block to cleanup before continuing.

FYI, this is your code in your environment so this represents the structure you should be aiming for - you may need to fix other coding errors (since I've already noticed coding errors with the template string declarations - there may be others).

Here's a way to do all of those:

```
//import devices from './puppeteerDevices'
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { devices } = puppeteer;

const testedMobileDevices = ["Galaxy Note 3", "Galaxy Note 3 landscape", "Galaxy Note II", "Galaxy Note II landscape",
    "Galaxy S III", "Galaxy S III landscape", "Galaxy S5", "Galaxy S5 landscape", "iPad", "iPad landscape",
    "iPad Mini", "iPad Mini landscape", "iPad Pro", "iPad Pro landscape", "iPhone 4", "iPhone 4 landscape",
    "iPhone 5", "iPhone 5 landscape", "iPhone 6", "iPhone 6 landscape", "iPhone 6 Plus", "iPhone 6 Plus landscape",
    "iPhone 7", "iPhone 7 landscape", "iPhone 7 Plus", "iPhone 7 Plus landscape", "iPhone 8", "iPhone 8 landscape",
    "iPhone 8 Plus", "iPhone 8 Plus landscape", "iPhone SE", "iPhone SE landscape", "iPhone X",
    "iPhone X landscape", "iPhone XR", "iPhone XR landscape", "iPhone 11", "iPhone 11 landscape", "iPhone 11 Pro",
    "iPhone 11 Pro landscape", "iPhone 11 Pro Max", "iPhone 11 Pro Max landscape", "Nexus 10", "Nexus 10 landscape",
    "Nexus 4", "Nexus 4 landscape", "Nexus 5", "Nexus 5 landscape", "Nexus 5X", "Nexus 5X landscape", "Nexus 6",
    "Nexus 6 landscape", "Nexus 6P", "Nexus 6P landscape", "Nexus 7", "Nexus 7 landscape", "Pixel 2",
    "Pixel 2 landscape", "Pixel 2 XL", "Pixel 2 XL landscape"
];

async function login() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const username = 'andrewbregman';
    const password = 'randompassword120948acndkla';
    const base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/';

    await page.goto(`${base_url}/login`);
    await page.type('[name=username]', username);
    await page.type('[name=password]', password);
    await page.click('[type=submit]');
    await page.waitFor(5000);
}

async function test() {
    for (let device of testedMobileDevices) {
        await login();
        const base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
        const urls = ['myprojects', 'home', 'notifications']
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
        const page = await browser.newPage()

        await page.emulate(device);

        for (let url or urls) {
            await page.goto(`${ base_url }/url`);
            await page.screenshot({
                path: "./screenshot.jpg",
                type: "jpeg",
                fullPage: true
            });
            await page.waitFor(100);
        }
    }
}

test().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Great response, thank you! Do you recommend any resources for learning async functions more in-depth?

Comment: @AndrewBregman - First make sure you fully know promises because `await` and `async` are only useful when you have asynchronous operations tied to promises.  A few resources: [Using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), [Async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) and [Modern Javascript with promises and async/await](https://nodejs.dev/learn/modern-asynchronous-javascript-with-async-and-await).

Comment: Just an FYI, I just posted another question related to this. The testedMobileDevices list returns an error that it is not iterable. I've looked up similar problems, but can't find a compatible solution, if you'd like to check out the problem and answer it, I've just made a new post. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewBregman - It seems you already have your answer over there.  Your array declaration was not correct.  It should work the way it is in my answer here.

Comment: Okay, sorry to bug but I get the error TypeError: cannot read property 'isMobile' of undefined?

Answer (score 1):

you need to make the function which pass to `testedMobileDevices.map` `async`:

```
const test = async () => {
testedMobileDevices.map(async(device) => {
login();
const base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
const urls = ['myprojects', 'home', 'notifications']
const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
const page = await browser.newPage()

await page.emulate(device)

urls.forEach(goUrls); 
const goUrls = async (url) =>{
    await page.goto({base_url}/url)
    page.screenshot({
        path: "./screenshot.jpg",
        type: "jpeg",
        fullPage: true})
    await page.waitFor(100);
}
})}
```

Comment: It's pointless to use `.map()` if the return value isn't looked at, and `.map()` doesn't care about `async` functions anyway. The only thing to do is pass the return value to `Promise.all()` or something like that.

Comment: FYI, this implementation will have no way for the caller to know when it's done or if there was an error.

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay. So to fix this? Where would I put try and catch(err)?

Comment: @dev55555 I am getting Unhandled Promise Rejection Warnings after running the script wit hthis implementation.

Comment: It was more involved than a simple comment to explain how this should be written so I've added my own answer to illustrate.